# Add custom description to woocommerce shop-site based on IDs

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a custom description to my woocommerce shop. I would like to show a different description on the shop and the description (when click on the product) would remain as it was written on the shop.

And I would like to separate it. The only way i see it, it's by using some custom html with php but I have no idea. CSS didn't seem to help. Since I have various products, I'd like to separate it differently by product ID and write the description myself for each of them in order to make it look like:

This is my file oceanwp-strings.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * OceanWP theme strings
 *
 * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'oceanwp_theme_strings' ) ) {

    /**
     * OceanWP Theme Strings
     *
     *  @author Amit Singh (apprimit@gmail.com)
     *  @since 1.8.5
     *
     * @param  string  $value  String key.
     * @param  boolean $echo   Print string.
     * @return mixed           Return string or nothing.
     */
    function oceanwp_theme_strings( $value, $echo = true ) {

        $oceanwp_strings = apply_filters(
            'oceanwp_theme_strings',
            array(

                'owp-string-header-skip-link'            => apply_filters( 'ocean_header_skip_link', __( 'Skip to content', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-search-text'                 => apply_filters( 'ocean_search_text', __( 'Search', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-mobile-search-text'          => apply_filters( 'ocean_mobile_search_text', __( 'Search', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-mobile-fs-search-text'       => apply_filters( 'ocean_mobile_fs_search_text', __( 'Type your search', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-header-replace-search-text'  => apply_filters( 'ocean_header_replace_search_text', __( 'Type then hit enter to search...', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-search-overlay-search-text'  => apply_filters( 'ocean_search_overlay_search_text', __( 'Type then hit enter to search', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-vertical-header-search-text' => apply_filters( 'ocean_vertical_header_search_text', __( 'Search...', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-medium-header-search-text'   => apply_filters( 'ocean_medium_header_search_text', __( 'Search...', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-logout-text'         => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_logout_text', __( 'Log out of this account', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-placeholder'         => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_placeholder', __( 'Your comment here...', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-profile-edit'        => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_profile_edit', __( 'Click to edit your profile', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-post-button'         => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_post_button', __( 'Post Comment', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-name-req'            => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_name_req', __( 'Name (required)', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-email-req'           => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_email_req', __( 'Email (required)', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-name'                => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_name', __( 'Name', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-email'               => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_email', __( 'Email', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-comment-website'             => apply_filters( 'ocean_comment_website', __( 'Website', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-search-continue-reading'     => apply_filters( 'ocean_search_continue_reading', __( 'Continue Reading', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-post-continue-reading'       => apply_filters( 'ocean_post_continue_reading', __( 'Continue Reading', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-single-related-posts'        => apply_filters( 'ocean_single_related_posts', __( 'You Might Also Like', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-single-next-post'            => apply_filters( 'ocean_single_next_post', __( 'Next Post', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-single-prev-post'            => apply_filters( 'ocean_single_prev_post', __( 'Previous Post', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-single-screen-reader-rm'     => apply_filters( 'ocean_single_screen_reader_rm', __( 'Read more articles', 'oceanwp' ) ),

                // Woocommerce.
                'owp-string-woo-quick-view-text'         => apply_filters( 'ocean_woo_quick_view_text', __( 'Quick View', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-woo-quick-view-close'        => apply_filters( 'ocean_woo_quick_view_close', __( 'Close quick preview', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-woo-floating-bar-select-btn' => apply_filters( 'ocean_woo_floating_bar_select_btn', __( 'Select Options', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-woo-floating-bar-selected'   => apply_filters( 'ocean_woo_floating_bar_selected', __( 'Selected:', 'oceanwp' ) ),
                'owp-string-woo-floating-bar-out-stock'  => apply_filters( 'ocean_woo_floating_bar_out_stock', __( 'Out of stock', 'oceanwp' ) ),
            )
        );

        if ( is_rtl() ) {
            // do your stuff.
        }

        $owp_string = isset( $oceanwp_strings[ $value ] ) ? $oceanwp_strings[ $value ] : '';

        /**
         * Print or return strings
         */
        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $owp_string; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        } else {
            return $owp_string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want a _different_ description? It rather sounds like you entered the correct description already, it just gets _output_ in an unsuitable format on the shop page. So the template portion that is responsible for the latter, should probably be modified accordingly.

Comment: I don't want another actually. I just want to display it properly. I've uploaded the template (or what i think it's the template) that my theme is using. Thanks for describing my issue on a better way.

Answer (score 1):

What you call description is actually `the_excerpt();`. It's pretty much a short version of your post content. You can learn more about it here @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/ and here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/

Now that confusion is out of the way, as each themeam is different, you probably have somewhere in your theme file a template part for your products. i'm gonna need the file's code to go further.

Edit your post with the product template part code and I will take a look.

---

**EDIT 1.2: BEFORE DOING ANYTHING SAVE A COPY OF THE PRODUCT TEMPLATE IN A SAFE PLACE**

```
if ( ! $length ) {
   echo wp_kses_post( strip_shortcodes( $post->post_excerpt ) );
} else {
   echo wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( $post->post_excerpt ), $length );
}
```

this is used to fetch the excerpt from the database `$post->post_excerpt`. No formating is associated with it.

We're gonna use `get_the_excerpt()` as the formating is passed on.

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/*

```
if ( ! $length ) {
   echo strip_shortcodes( 'EDIT 1.2:'.get_the_excerpt() );
} else {
   echo wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( 'EDIT 1.2:'.get_the_excerpt()  ), $length );
}
```

Comment: You are right. It's the excerpt. I've updated it. I hope i got the right one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see EDIT 1.1 in regards to your last comment. If that answers your question don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I edited as described and it didn't seem to work. There were no changes. I even clear out the cache to be sure and used another browser to see it.

Comment: Are you writing the excerpt yourself? Or is it automatic?

Comment: I wrote it myself on the options for products, under WooCommerce/Products. Might it be that all the info is written on "short description"? I tried to make a test writing something on the text area where the description should be (i change to the short one to show it next to the image at product sites) but the description didn't change at the shop page.

Comment: Can you see EDIT 1.2, i've removed `wp_kses_post` which removes html5 tags. I've added the text 'EDIT 1.2' so we know we're in the right place (that should be appended in front of your product excerpt).

Comment: I edit it with the "EDIT 1.2" and it did appeared before the text. The rest of it, remained the same as before editing anything.

Comment: I've tested  `get_the_excerpt` on my end and it's working fine, this is where the problem is happening probably `do_action( 'ocean_after_archive_product_description' );`, and i'm gonna need your  `function.php ` file if you can edit your post

Comment: I have uploaded the functions. I deleted some things like info about the headers for example, since it passed 30000 characters. I hope i pasted the one you need to look at.

Comment: It's calling from an other file called `oceanwp-strings.php` can you edit with that file instead

Comment: It took me a while to found the file [oceanwp-strings.php] but it´s on the description.